# Scheduler plot to visualize a build process

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot2 for this but have no idea where to look. I have a global start and end time `min(begin)` and `max(end)` respectively which is my x axis. My y axis would be each processor and my data includes for each processor the time chunks where the compiler would be busy compiling or linking a specific file. I would like to see the empty areas where a Processor is idle. My df would look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(proc = as.factor(c('P_1', 'P_1', 'P_1', 'P_2', 'P_2', 'P_3')), begin=c(1, 20, 23 , 3, 5, 8), end=c(5, 19, 21, 4, 9, 100), what=c('compiling A', 'compiling B', 'linking A', 'compiling C', 'compiling D', 'compiling E'))
df
> df
  proc begin end        what
1  P_1     1   5 compiling A
2  P_1    20  19 compiling B
3  P_1    23  21   linking A
4  P_2     3   4 compiling C
5  P_2     5   9 compiling D
6  P_3     8 100 compiling E
>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=begin, xend=end, y=proc, yend=proc, colour=what)) + 
  geom_segment(size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: +1! For this small amount of data this works fine, but if the number of things the processor does (compiling z, linking x, etc) the number of categories get's real big real soon. The OP wants to know which processor is idle, you could just show if there is activity or not (TRUE/FALSE) or maybe only the categories Linking/Compiling...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra You mean remove the colour coding, and thus the legend? Yes, I agree that makes sense.

Comment: either remove the color entirely, or reduce the amount of possible classes to say only (compiling, linking, etc).